# Castle Windsor and creating instances as a factory

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I need to get N instances of an object where I won't know N until run time BUT I'm also trying to avoid any container calls within my own code.

In Spring you would do the following...

1. Create an interface (which we'll call IFactory) with a method like CreateFoo();
2. Register the IFactory interface with Spring but configured so that it knows to treat it like a factory.
3. In your class ask for IFactory which spring will of course provide you with.
4. Call CreateFoo() on IFactory.  Spring will intercept your call and create an instance of Foo for you.

Does anyone know if this possible in Windsor and how I would go about doing it?  Or even some way of accomplishing my goal (get N instances of something WITHOUT talking directly to the container).

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Castle Windsor has the [Typed Factory Facility](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx) to address exactly this scenario.